# Google Drive API for attaching files

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-android-api

We have old gdata libraries for Document List API and there is a method for Attchments. We are changing it to Drive API but we are ot finding anything related to attachments in Drive API. Do we have to use Files.insert instead? Please advise.

Comment: Any good coding sample that can be shared will be extremely useful. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Attachments, but you should check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/) for samples. The Quickstarts are also a good place to start from.

Comment: Thanks Andy. This is the sequence of events in my Attachment method that I want to implement using DRIVE API : Exports a document and prepares it to be sent as an attachment.
   * 
   * param docUrl  The URL of the document.
   * return -   The exported doc as a {link MimeBodyPart} for emailing or {code null} if any errors occurred.

Comment: Attaching what to what?

Comment: Attaching a URL to an email. The URL is the physical Google spreadsheet. It looks like this is attached to an email.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is share a document with a group of people and send the URL for that document to them via email. You are correct that you would use the [Files.Insert API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) call to upload the document and then [Permissions.Insert API)(https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) call to share with people. I'm not sure how you're sending the email, but you can use the selfLink/alternateLink fields in the Files.Insert response to share with people, or you could try the Gmail APIs.

Comment: Thanks Grant. Appreciate it.